# Unable to set text box value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Todo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      amount:1000000
    }
   }
  handleChange= (e)=> {
    const number= Number(e.target.value).toLocaleString();
    console.log(number);
    this.setState({
      amount: number
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.amount.toLocaleString()}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am a new front end developer. 
I am unable to change the value of my textbox with more than 9,999.
I get NaN

https://codesandbox.io/s/y2lrywpk21

Comment: Your code sandbox doesn't appear to match your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is once you get into the thousands, you introduce commas. The comma is causing an issue when you try to convert it to a number. Use this to strip the commas: `.replace(/,/g, '')`.

You should also only use `.toLocalString` when displaying the value. There's no need to use it when setting state and when reading state.

Working example:

```js
class Todo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      amount:1000000
    }
   }
  handleChange= (e)=> {
    const number= Number(e.target.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
    console.log(number);
    this.setState({
      amount: number
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.amount.toLocaleString()}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Thank You for explaining me the issue. Works now

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using toLocaleString?

toLocaleString is used to translate a number into language specific formats i.e. using commas when dealing with US English or using decimals when dealing with German language and other European languages. 3,000 vs 3.000 for example.

Check out the documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

I think you’re misusing toLocaleString. Also, check out the disclaimer at the bottom of the docs pertaining to using this function with large numbers.